# How to custom index label on each bar chart using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am developing a site in which I use bar chart and I can't find a way to customize the bar chart in order to show the value on each bar chart.

**Here is my bar chart js**

```
$(function(){
        var t;
        function size(animate){
            if (animate == undefined){
                animate = false;
            }
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = setTimeout(function(){
                $("#bar-chart-js").each(function(i,el){
                    $(el).attr({
                        "width":$(el).parent().width(),
                        "height":$(el).parent().outerHeight()
                    });
                });
                redraw(animate);
                var m = 0;
                $(".chartJS").height("");
                $(".chartJS").each(function(i,el){ m = Math.max(m,$(el).height()); });
                $(".chartJS").height(m);
            }, 30);
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function(){ size(false); });

        function redraw(animation){
            var options = {};
            if (!animation){
                options.animation = true;
            } else {
                options.animation = true;
            }
            var dataJson1 = <?php echo json_encode($monthly_income);?>;
            var dataJson2 = <?php echo json_encode($monthly_expense);?>;
            var data1 =  $.map(dataJson1, function(el) { return el; });
            var data2 =  $.map(dataJson2, function(el) { return el; });
            //console.log(dataJson1);
            //console.log('data1:' + data1);
            var barChartData = {
                labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "#79D1CF",
                        strokeColor : "#79D1CF",
                        data : data1
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "#E67A77",
                        strokeColor : "#E67A77",
                        data : data2
                    }
                ]
            };
            var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-js").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
        }
        size(true);
    });
```

**I want to show the index label as the image below**

[image]

Please help me out and I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: check this link for once : https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/770

Comment: @A.J - I did follow this, but it not work. That the reason I decided to ask here again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the labels in the animationComplete callback

```
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-js").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y);
            });
        })
    }
});
```

I've turned off tooltips assuming you don't need them any longer (since the same information is being shown in the newly added labels). If you need the tooltips, then you need to extend the Bar chart and move the above logic to after each time the chart is drawn.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/geaje18p/ (I replaced your php echo with hard coded arrays)

---

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geaje18p/ This giving me error as "Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Bar is not a function"
If Someone found working please help me out.